# Simulation in Python

Tags: python, software, simulation

What is the most common package for discrete-event simulation in the OR community?
I have found [SimPy](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "discrete-event simulation"?

Comment: I think SimPy is the most common in the python world (at least, it is the one for which I can find the most examples), however, you can have a look at Salabim https://www.salabim.org/, ManPy http://www.manpy-simulation.org/ and CiW https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Do you really want something that uses Python? That's mentioned in the title, but the question text doesn't mention Python at all.

Comment: Related: [A review of open source discrete event simulation software for operations research](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281391626_A_review_of_open_source_discrete_event_simulation_software_for_operations_research)

Answer (score 6):

Although this question is subjective (as noted in the paper below), I believe that there is enough research done on this topic to make it more answerable.

### [Dias *et al.* (2016)](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc16papers/095.pdf)

The paper is very much like a systematic review. However, the paper ranks *commercial* discrete-event simulation software, rather than the open-source *SimPy* your have mentioned. Results are below.

> In fact, apart from *Arena* – **by far the best classification tool with 9.9 out of 10 points** – and from the last four tools – *SimCAD Pro*, *GPSS World*, *SLX + Proof 3D*
> and *ShowFlow* – the remaining tools are closely ranked.

---

Here is the breakdown. Content in bullet points is extracted from the paper.

---

- *Arena*, *ProModel*, *AutoMod* and *SIMPROCESS* are the tools with the most presence in the WSC and Plant Simulation, *QUEST*, *SimCAD Pro* and *ShowFlow* are the ones with the least WSC presence.

Note: WSC = Winter Simulation Conference.

- Three new parameters [...] were added: Scopus, Google Books and
  number of published books related to the tool. *Arena*, *ProModel* and *SIMPROCESS* are the tools with most presence in these documents databases. In their turns, *SimCAD Pro*, *SLX + Proof 3D* and *Showflow* are the ones with the lowest factor parameter values.

The following analysis was obtained by using existing reviews and surveys.

- Considering all the obtained average factor parameters values, *Arena*, *ProModel* and *Simul8* obtained the best results, whilst *ProcessModel* and *GPSS* obtained the lowest values.

In terms of social networks such as Google+ and Twitter, the rankings are as follows.

- The lack of significant presence of some tools in this frame should be stressed, c.f. *Micro Saint*, *GPSS World* and *ShowFlow*. On the other hand, *Arena* and *FlexSim* are the tools with the most presence in social networks.

The following analysis (Google search) is very similar to that for Google books so one should expect similar results.

- *Arena*, *ProModel*, *Micro Saint* and *ProcessModel* are the tools with higher
  Google search results. On the other hand, *SimCAD Pro*, *GPSS* and *SLX* obtained the lowest values.

Calculating the proportion of search results, *Arena* wins again.

- *Arena* and *Simio* are the tools with the best result for these parameters, indicating that these are the 2 tools with most growth in search results over the last 5 years. [...] *ShowFlow* got the lowest value.

---

<sub>Reference</sub>

<sub>[1] Dias, L. M. S., Vieira, A. A. C., Pereira, G. A. B., Oliveira, J. A. (2016). Discrete Simulation Software Ranking - A Top List Of The Worldwide Most Popular And Used Tools. *Proceedings of the 2016 Winter Simulation Conference.* INFORMS.</sub>